# How to extend External Language Input?

Tags: external-calls

Is it possible to add a new option here and bind an evaluator?

[image]

Is it possible to take SageMath, Matlab, Maple, etc. as examples to provide a **complete process** demonstration?

Comment: Add it to the stylesheet so that it goes with ```CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "ExternalLanguage", CellFrameLabels}]```. It seems the menu there changes a `CellEvaluationLanguage` option.

Answer (score 7):

**It was just an attempt to add a ExternalCell, and did not successfully create an evaluator bind.**

[image]

1. First create a new package called `ExternalEvaluate_*`, only this form can be recognized by External Evaluator Manager.
2. Then add cell icon and set `"ShowInFrontendCellQ"` as `True`.
3. Then run the `` ExternalEvaluate`RegisterSystem ``.

```
ExternalEvaluate`RegisterSystem["SageMath",
    <|
        "ExecutablePathFunction" -> Function[{vers}, unimplement[]],
        "ExecutablePatternFunction" -> Function[{vers}, unimplement[]],
        "ProgramFileFunction" -> Function[{version}, PacletManager`PacletResource["ExternalEvaluate_SageMath", "REPL"]],
        "ScriptExecCommandFunction" -> Function[{uuid, exec, file, opts}, unimplement[]],

        "Icon" -> Import[PacletManager`PacletResource["ExternalEvaluate_SageMath", "Icon"]],
        "IconCell" -> ToBoxes@Import[PacletManager`PacletResource["ExternalEvaluate_SageMath", "IconCell"]],
        "ShowInFrontendCellQ" -> True,

        "VersionExecCommandFunction" -> Function[{exec}, unimplement[]],
        "PacletName" -> Automatic,
        "SessionProlog" -> None,

        "DeserializationFunction" -> BinaryDeserialize,
        "SerializationFunction" -> BinarySerialize
    |>
  ];
```

Then a new kind of External Cell is available.

But it needs to bind executable program, still have no idea.